# Configure CodeIgniter to show correct file path for images, etc

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

I have a CodeIgniter project handed to me by its original developer. I was able to run its home page but the images and links are not working.

My project's path is at `http://localhost/my_project.`

Upon inspection, all the images' file paths are directed at this fashion: `http://localhost/images/image_name.jpg`

(Meaning the `my_project` path is skipped.)

I'm thinking of configuring `.htaccess` so all resources' location will be directed correctly but I wasn't able to do so.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use base_url
in config.php
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/my_project';

View file:

Comment: Did not work for me. But when I put my `images` folder on the same directory as `my_project`, the images shows up! (Literally following the url) Does that give more clue on solving the problem?

Comment: Define Base Path in index.php
Step:
1. $images_path        = "images";
2. if (realpath($images_path) !== FALSE)
{
 $images_path = realpath($images_path).'/';
}
3. define('IMAGESPATH', str_replace("\\", "/", $images_path));

Comment: Still not working. Additional info: `Filename: core/Common.php, Line Number: 257`shows up. I'm not sure if that is related.

Comment: System->core->Common.php
Line no. 257
return $_config[0] =& $config;
Replce with:
$_config[0] =& $config;
return $_config[0];

Comment: Thanks for your replies @Bushra. The `Common.php` error is now fixed. Unfortunately, the images are still not showing up, and the links are still broken.

Comment: You should put part of code from view to explain how you echo image path (i.e. `<img scr="what_do_you_have_here" alt="alt name"/>`).

Comment: Hi @Tpojka and @Bushra. The project's css and images have this format `<img src="/images/menu-about.jpg" />` so i'm thinking I have to redirect the image and css source somehow. I don't want to edit those files. Is there anyway I could fix it on config or htaccess?

Comment: Post your `.htaccess` file. Also missing slash there: `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/my_project/';// here`.